# Detecting movement on a recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView showing a gridlayout for Calendar days for a month. I am trying to be able to swipe left or right to move forward or backwards through months.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llDayHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnSelectDate">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSelectedDate"
            style="@style/dateHeader"
            android:text="Date" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHdrDay1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Day"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHdrDay2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Day"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHdrDay3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Day"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHdrDay4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Day"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHdrDay5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Day"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHdrDay6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Day"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHdrDay7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Day"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvCalenderMonthDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/ezyOrange" />
```

If  I add a swipe listener to the rvCalendarMonthDisplay is only works occasionally, (I suspect when the finger touches the bits between the days). I have changed the swipe listener to be on the llDayHeader and this works fine if you swipe on the Month at the top but I want to be able to swipe on the calendar area. Is this possible or does the recyclerView trap the touch or is the adapter grabbing the event.  [image]

I have the following code in the activity.

```
        //  Listeners
    rvCalenderMonthDisplay.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
        public void onSwipeTop() {
        }

        public void onSwipeRight() {
            displayDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
            processDate();
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            displayDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            processDate();
        }

        public void onSwipeBottom() {
        }

    });



     @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    calendarLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 7);
    rvCalenderMonthDisplay.setLayoutManager(calendarLayoutManager);



private void refreshScreen() {
    myCalendarAdapter = new CalendarDataAdapter(this, calendarEntries, displayDate);
    rvCalenderMonthDisplay.setAdapter(myCalendarAdapter);
}
```

Any clues please anyone.